# Python - call function from python33.dll (access violation)

Tags: python, dll, sublimetext3, ctypes

I have this code:

```
import ctypes


lib = ctypes.WinDLL('python33.dll')
print(lib['PyRun_SimpleString'])

func = lib['PyRun_SimpleString']

func.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]
func.restype = ctypes.c_int

arg = "print(':P')"
arg = arg.encode('utf-8')

func(arg)
```

result:

```
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000004
```

Running using sublime text (python3.3 embedding)

Answer (score 2):

Use [PyDLL](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#ctypes.PyDLL), not WinDLL.  From the documentation:

> Instances of this class behave like CDLL instances, except that the Python GIL is not released during the function call, and after the function execution the Python error flag is checked. If the error flag is set, a Python exception is raised.
>
> Thus, this is only useful to call Python C api functions directly.